# I was watching a tutorial on unity but I came across these errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

everything is in unity

[image: the errors]

[image: code 1]

[image: code 2]

If anyone can help me I am new

This is the code for `PlayerInput`:

https://pastebin.com/hWNPVmZJ

Comment: `playerVelocity` is never actually set so it's null.

Comment: Can you also share `PlayerInput`?

Comment: here is the player input code https://pastebin.com/hWNPVmZJ

Comment: I think I got what all of u meant but where do I need to change its value.I found similar code which I think it is finished?https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html
and it looks like mine I think

Answer (score 0):

NullRefereenceException usually refer that there's a variable/field is not set/ initialized
during my intial review of your code there is playerVelocity field in PlayerMotor which is not initilized in the start or awake methods and its a private  field  so i also assumed that  you didnt set value for it  from inspector too

so in processMove method you are trying to access to playerVelocity which has a null as value